# Get the PID of all processes killed with pkill?

Tags: linux, bash

I am doing:

```
pkill -9 -f stringMatch
```

If successful or not successful nothing is sent to STDOUT. Can anyone suggest a portable way to return the PIDs of the processes that were killed?

Comment: Couldn't you just use pgrep with the same selection criteria before executing the pkill command?

Comment: You could use pgrep to grab all of the PIDs. If you really wanted to get fancy you could write a script and loop through the PIDs that pgrep found and then kill them one by one checking to make sure they were killed properly each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `man` page:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      One or more processes matched the criteria.
       1      No processes matched.
       2      Syntax error in the command line.
       3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

So based on `$?`, the exit code, you can tell if any processes were killed ("success"), or not. You cannot know the details. So if you want to know the PIDs getting killed, your only option is to get the list of processes, loop over them and kill one by one, for example:

```
for pid in $(pgrep stringMatch); do
    kill $pid && echo killed $pid || echo could not kill $pid
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up pgreping the list of PIDs, running pkill on all, then pgrepping again (checking if empty string or not), if not echo return value + PIDs unsuccessful.

Comment: I don't see why you need to `pgrep` again. You could do all that in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to first use `pgrep` to get the list of PIDs, then use that list to send signals to them with `kill`.